# how to get values at html5 data-attribute in selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

i want to get value from `"value":"165796011"` which in `data-gbfilter-checkbox`

I used

```
element= driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#widgetFilters > div:nth-child(1) > div.a-row.a-expander-container.a-expander-inline-container > span:nth-child(3)')
print(element.get_attribute('data-gbfilter-checkbox'))
```

but it give me all data which between `data-gbfilter-checkbox` bractes

HTML:

```
<span class="a-declarative" data-action="gbfilter-checkbox" data-gbfilter-checkbox="
{"attribute":"whitelist_categories","value":"165796011","rangeEnd":"","rangeStart":"","filterType":"checkboxes"}">
</span>
```

i solved it but now( i don't want to write 7 ,I want it with dynamic way)

great I converted the string to list and value number 7, but it's the static way I want to find numbers by the dynamic way ( i don't want to write 7 I want it with dynamic way)

```
 pages= driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#widgetFilters > div:nth-child(1) > div.a-row.a-expander-container.a-expander-inline-container > div > span:nth-child(25)')

 list= pages.get_attribute('data-gbfilter-checkbox').split('"') print(list[7])
```

Comment: You will have to parse the string to get what you are looking for.

Comment: great I converted the string to list and value number 7, but it's the static way I want to find numbers by the dynamic way ( i don't want to write 7 I want it with dynamic way) ```pages= driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#widgetFilters > div:nth-child(1) > div.a-row.a-expander-container.a-expander-inline-container > div > span:nth-child(25)')
list= pages.get_attribute('data-gbfilter-checkbox').split('"')
print(list[7])```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse that into json and then reference the field:

```
import json
json = json.loads(pages.get_attribute('data-gbfilter-checkbox'))

# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(json["value"])
```